# Simple for loop I can't figure out

Tags: c++

I'm kind of new to C++ so last night I thought of something.  I want to print out numbers from 1-100 but with 10 numbers per line.  I'm aware my code is below is wrong as it just prints 1-100 vertically.  If anyone can shed some light to my question, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for reading :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        cout << x << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about [`if` statements](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html)? and the [modulus operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to print 10 numbers, then a carriage return, and then 10 numbers, then a carriage return, and so on, correct?

If so, how about something like:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
    cout << x << " ";
    if ((x%10)==0) cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code prints numbers like so:

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100.

I want: 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
and so on.

Comment: @reppo: Why would you just say what you think the code does instead of testing it? Especially since you are, as you say, new to C++.

Comment: @reppo I'm afraid you have made some sort of transcription error. What Jeremy Friesner has posted will perform as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator `%` to determine if a number is a multiple of another:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
    if( x % 10 == 0 ) cout << endl;
    cout << x << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int main() {
       for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
        cout << x << " " ; //Add a space
        if ( x % 10 == 0 ) {
            cout << endl //Put out a new line after every 10th entry?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print new line when it can be device by 10.

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {

    cout << x << ",";

    if ((x % 10) == 0) {

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        i%10==0 ? cout << i<<endl : cout<<i<<" ";
    }
```